# Smart cropping document image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I looked for a crop that automatically cuts the image and that only the document that is in the photo remains.

And created a module where my work colleagues upload their medical, shopping, etc. receipts. They take a photo and it goes up, but many times half of the photo is with a background. And I looked for some kind of crop, in JavaScript or PHP to cut these images automatically.

But I can't find anything to do an auto crop. Is there any such thing?

Original Image:

[image]

Final Image:

[image]

Is it possible to do this cut automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ImageMagick::trimImage.  It may take some tuning, but if there's always a pretty good contrast between the page and the background, it will work.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.trimimage.php